# "Undefined reference to" errors using numpy array in C++

Tags: python, c++, numpy, gcc

I'm trying to compile some C++ code into a dll to import into Python for the first time. I want to be able to return a Numpy array from one of the functions, with an example line that looks like `lNumpyArray = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData( 2, lDimensions, NPY_UINT8, (void*)lImage->GetDataPointer() );`

At the start of the code I have included `Python.h` and `arrayobject.h`.

Using GCC (working on Windows) I have been able to compile the code to a .O file without errors. However, when trying to go to a dll, I'm getting a lot of errors like `undefined reference to '__imp__Py_Dealloc'`. From my limited understanding, it might be because I'm missing a library somewhere in the linker. Is there some other library I need to include for using Numpy arrays in C, or should I be looking elsewhere? The gcc command I've been using is included below.

`gcc -Wall -shared Pipeline.cpp -I"C:/Python38/include" -I"C:/Program Files/Pleora Technologies Inc/eBUS SDK/Includes" -I "C:/Python38/Lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include" -L"C:/Python38/libs" -L"C:/Program Files/Pleora Technologies Inc/eBUS SDK/Libraries" -o lib.dll -lPvBuffer64 -lPvDevice64 -lPvStream64 -lPvAppUtils64 -lPvSystem64 -lSimpleImagingLib64 -lPvGenICam64 -lPvSerial64 -lPvBase64 -lPtUtilsLib64`

Comment: Please make this a [mcve].

Comment: You forgot to link with the python library. https://docs.python.org/3.8/extending/windows.html *you must pass pythonXY.lib to the linker*.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using the C Python interface to numpy and use a library link xtensor ([found here](https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor-python)).